# How to protect SQL Server Database from accidental deletion?

Tags: sql-server, database

I would like to somehow protect databases on my SQL Server from being deleted without entering a password, even by someone with administrative access. There are times where a database has been deleted accidentally (for example, when two databases have similar names) and I'd like to prevent this from being an easy mistake to make.

I'm also open to any suggestions or alternative ideas on how to handle this. Thank you!

Comment: I think this would be more suited to dba.stackexchange

Comment: Train your DBA's to be responsible for their work? It might seem harsh, but for something like dropping a database, you should be ensuring that you're double checking the database you're about the drop is the correct one. This seems more like a process/mind set issue.

Comment: hehe I think you meant to say "SQL Server from being deleted **with** entering a password". :)

Comment: Not sure how entering a password prevents dropping the wrong database.

Comment: You could create a server-level DDL trigger as an added level of protection against accidental database deletion. The implementation is entirely up to you as to how hard you want the drop to be.

Comment: @Larnu If one's dev workflow makes it easy to initialise a new database then dropping a database becomes an inconsequential action. Unless one pops up the wrong window in the early hours, which I did, and I deleted a live database. But, lucky for me, it didn't work because it was in use. Especially lucky actually because I'd restarted the server.

Comment: Dropping a database is rarely inconsequential, @IanWarburton . In fact, doing so in a live environment if very likely the *complete* opposite. Even in a Dev environment it has consequences. About the only place it isn't in in a Sandbox environment. But none of this chanhes my point; take responsibility for your actions and check your work. If you make sure you're connected to the right instance before you drop a database, the problem is almost immediately negated. Checking you're dropping the right database along side thatgrealy helps too. A lack of checking doesn't alleviate you of fault.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Server Level Trigger that Rolls back any attempt to delete a database.

The Trigger will need to be disabled then re-enabled to perform any legitimate deletions.

```
USE [master]
GO


    CREATE TRIGGER [Trig_Prevent_Drop_Database] ON ALL SERVER
    FOR DROP_DATABASE
    AS
        RAISERROR('Dropping of databases has been disabled on this server.', 16,1);
        ROLLBACK;


    GO

    DISABLE TRIGGER [Trig_Prevent_Drop_Database] ON ALL SERVER
    GO
```

Or as a process:

1. Create a single-column, one row table in Master that will hold a database name.
2. Insert the name of the database in the Table.
3. Add an If statement to the trigger to check if the Database being dropped is identical to the Database in the table created in step 1. Otherwise Roll-back.

In this case you wouldn't need to disable the Trigger. But you're creating 2 points in the process where you define the database name.

Capturing the Database Name in a Server Level Trigger should be possible with:

```
SELECT     CAST(eventdata().query('/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName[1]/text()') as NVarchar(128))
```

Comment: That would help against "accidental" dropping (but, in all honesty, if you type `DROP DATABASE ImportantDatabase; GO` and hit execute "accidentally" then I judge what you're opinion of an accident is), however, that doesn't really fix typing `DROP DATABASE DB1;` instead of `DROP DATABASE DB12;` after you've disabled the trigger.